# How to remove "whitespace" in between images and side of explorer in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, whitespace

I am using bootstrap and the images have this whitespace in between them which I can't seem to remove

I've tried setting the max width, object-fit, and floating to left, and removing padding

```html
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .top {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .imageStyle{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

    }
    .c {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7">
                    <img src="Images/Background.png" align="left" class="img-fluid float-left imageStyle back">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 c">
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the no-gutters class in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Well, Bootstrap's `col-*` classes have built-in padding (`padding-left: 15px`, `padding-right: 15px`). You can remove that padding by assigning the class `px-0`** on the `col-7` div.

** sets `padding-left: 0` and `padding-right: 0`

see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBeMLy

---

Is that the source of your issue or do you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 0):

add * to your css it selects all of the elements in the DOM then remove padding and margin by adding padding: 0; and margin: 0;, try to replace the img tag with a div tag then add background-image to your css.

```css
*{
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
.image-style{
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1137745/pexels-photo-1137745.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 50vh;
}
.c{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-7 image-style">
      <!-- I M A G E -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 c">
    </div>           
  </div>
</div>
```